# Get multiple matches of a group in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying to get attributes from a BBCode using regular expression
Lets say I have those strings:

```
[icons a="1" b='2' c="3"]
[icons d="4" e='5' f="6"]
```

I need using a regular expression to get matches like this:

```
[
    {'a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3'},
    {'d', '4', 'e', '5', 'f', '6'}
]
```

I figured this regular expression:

```
\[icons[\w\s](?:(\w*)\=["|']([^"|']*))+.*?\]
```

But it only matches:

```
[
    {'a', '1'},
    {'d', '4'}
]
```

How  I can match all the attributes?

Also, just to make it more bullet proof, is there a way to match only the quote it found?

```
[icons a="1"] // GOOD
[icons a="1'] // BAD - But still a match
```

[Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/zW2dS1/2)

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: For this case it's irrelevant, but I use PHP.

Comment: @Vlad this is **always** relevant for regex questions. In your case, this information tells us we can use PCRE features in the answers.

Comment: Also, this would be trivial in .NET for instance, as its regex flavor actually stores all encountered occurrences of a capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to keep it simple:

Use one regex to match all the `[icons...]`:

```
\[icons\b[^\[\]]*\]
```

and a second regex to be used iteratively on each of this regex' matches:

```
(\w+)=(['"])((?:(?!\2).)*)\2
```

Note that the first and third group will contain your desired values, the second group contains the quote.

Comment: Yes this could be done, but it makes things maybe simple in the regex, but more complicated in the PHP.

Comment: There's no way around it, at least not in PHP. .NET has a regex engine that remembers individual captures of a repeated group, but PCRE doesn't.

Comment: I see... then I should replace the string, and on callback run another regexp to find the attributes... but how I can remove "[icons " from the replacement if the second regex doesn't return it? (without mentioning the word "icons")

Comment: Not so complicated. Iterate over the entire input using the first regex. For each match, iterate over that match with the second regex. Collect all matches in a dictionary or whatever that datastructure `{...}` is called in PHP. Collect all the dictionaries in a list.

Comment: Eventually this is what I did, but I wanted to keep things more simple using some smart Regex :-) but this also works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this may be this will help you

```
\[icons\s(\w)[=]["|'](\d)["|']\s(\w)[=]["|'](\d)["|']\s(\w)[=]["|'](\d)["|']\]
```